# Change Playback Quality of YTPlayerView

Tags: ios7, youtube, ios8, uiwebview, ytplayerview

I am having a problem with quality for embedded YouTube videos in my app. I am using `YTPlayerView` to embed videos from YouTube. My app has 2 options: option 1 is the user can watch video with 360p quality and option 2 is 720p quality. Are these two options possible? If yes, can I customize the video playback quality of the `YTPlayerView`?

I tried to change the quality this way, but it does not appear to work:

```
 [self.playerView setPlaybackQuality:kYTPlaybackQualitySmall];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using YouTube's [youtube-ios-player-helper](http://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) for iOS.

Unfortunately, due the to the nature of the iFrame API, it is not possible to force a quality playback with this library.  The player will load the video in the closest resolution to your `YTPlayerView`'s size.  If you change the size of your `YTPlayerView` programmatically, the view will reload the video to fit your new frame.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/66) on the project page.  Unfortunately, this is the expected behavior of the class.

Comment: Thanks JAL. I think I have to find another library. :(

Comment: @Duyklinsi unfortunately the youtube-ios-player-helper library is the only way to play YouTube videos in your app without violating their terms of service.  An alternate library is [XCDYouTubeKit](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit), but that violates YouTube's terms of service.