# Get a better video preview quality in iOS app using YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using `YTPlayerView` to play videos from Youtube in an iOS app. (See [Youtube Helper Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper))

And I'm facing a little issue that I would like to solve:
video previews have low quality when using the following method:

`- (void) cueVideoById:(NSString *)videoId startSeconds:(float)startSeconds suggestedQuality:(YTPlaybackQuality)suggestedQuality` , which is recommended to use when loading another video into web view.

If I use `- (BOOL) loadWithVideoId:(NSString *)videoId playerVars:(NSDictionary *)playerVars` , then preview quality is fine, but this will reload the web view, not recommended. See sample screenshots:

[image]
[image]

As suggested quality I use `kYTPlaybackQualityAuto`, also I tried the best ones without success.

How could I solve this and get a better preview quality without reloading videos every time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Playback Quality of YTPlayerView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237984/change-playback-quality-of-ytplayerview)

Answer (score 1):

Just call this method after initialising the player.

> [youtubePlayer setPlaybackQuality:kYTPlaybackQualityHD720];

Following are the possible values-

```html
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YTPlaybackQuality) {
    kYTPlaybackQualitySmall,
    kYTPlaybackQualityMedium,
    kYTPlaybackQualityLarge,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHD720,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHD1080,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHighRes,
    kYTPlaybackQualityAuto, /** Addition for YouTube Live Events. */
    kYTPlaybackQualityDefault,
    kYTPlaybackQualityUnknown /** This should never be returned. It is here for future proofing. */
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Is anything printing in the log? You can set breakpoint and check when the quality changes.

Comment: @RaduMatei implement the `didChangeToQuality` delegate method, log the `YTPlaybackQuality` quality returned from that video, and post the results back here.

Comment: YTPlayerView is used in my iOS app. How can I update or migrate the app? Because in the YTPlayerView there is UIWebView's are available.